# How could I implement K Nearest Neighbor in python which could get better accuracy from scratch

Tags: python, machine-learning

test_list

```
Power, Label
23.5, light
34.5, light
52.3, light
82.3, fan
102.2, fan
110.3, fan
```

train_list

```
tPower
24.3
32.5
45.3
```

```
def euclidean_distance(row1, row2, df):

    distance = 0.0

    #for row in range(len(df['tRealPower'])):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
            distance += (row['RealPower'] - row['tRealPower'])**2
            d = sqrt(distance)
            distlist.append(d)
    return distlist
```

Currently, the row1 is train list, row2 is test list but the result I got has error it display 2 list with the same set of value.

I was trying to implement KNN with reference to other resources but was unable to use on my task.

What I wanted to do is the have a set of train vale which have different appliance label which I hope when test value it is able to use K nearest Neaigbour classifier to get the closest to the set of vale for the different label and get a result of the [predicted label and accuracy

Comment: in function you append to `distlist` but you don't create it in function  - it may have wrong values.

Comment: @furas I added the list in the code this was part of my whole code,  but thx for pointing it out

Comment: you should remeber not only distance but also items for which you calculated this value.

Comment: I don't know why you use `df` and don't use `row1` and `row2`. You should get first item from test list and calculate distance to first item on training list and put on distlist, then calculate distance to second item on training list and put on list, etc. This way you will have list with distances between first test item and all training items and you can get K elements with smallest value to have its neaigbours for fist test item. Similar way you should to with second test item, and then with third item.

Comment: it seems I used names like in any other models - my "test list" means your "train_list", my "training list" means your "test_list"